# Setup continuous delivery in under 1 hour

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-integration, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to setup continuous delivery for a simple html page in under 1 hour?

Suppose I have a hello world index.html page being hosted by `npm serve`, a Dockerfile to build the image and a image.sh script using docker build. This is in a github repo.

I want to be able to check-in a change to the index.html file and see it on my website immediately.

Can this be done in under 1 hour. Either AWS or Google Cloud. What are the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question. 1 hour. Is it possible? Yes.

Using only AWS,

Services to be used:

- [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=codepipeline_b&sc_content=aws_codepipeline_e&sc_detail=aws%20codepipeline&sc_category=codepipeline&sc_segment=208316432832&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!208316432832!e!!g!!aws%20codepipeline&ef_id=WDMdcQAABOvSAh-G:20170810123702:s) - To trigger Github webhooks and send the source files to [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=codebuild_b&sc_content=code_build_e&sc_detail=aws%20codebuild&sc_category=codebuild&sc_segment=179121411526&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!179121411526!e!!g!!aws%20codebuild&ef_id=WDMdcQAABOvSAh-G:20170810123808:s)
- [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=codebuild_b&sc_content=code_build_e&sc_detail=aws%20codebuild&sc_category=codebuild&sc_segment=179121411526&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!179121411526!e!!g!!aws%20codebuild&ef_id=WDMdcQAABOvSAh-G:20170810123808:s) - Takes the source files from the `CodePipeline` and build your application, serve the build to S3, Heroku, Elastic Beanstalk, or any alternate service you desire

The Steps

1. Create an [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=codepipeline_b&sc_content=aws_codepipeline_e&sc_detail=aws%20codepipeline&sc_category=codepipeline&sc_segment=208316432832&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!208316432832!e!!g!!aws%20codepipeline&ef_id=WDMdcQAABOvSAh-G:20170810123702:s)
2. Attach your source(Github) in your Pipeline *(Each commit will trigger your pipeline to take the new commit and use it as a source and build it in CodeBuild)*
3. Using your custom Docker build environment, CodeBuild uses a yml file to specify the steps to take in your build process. Use it to build the newly committed source files, and deploy your app(s) using the AWS CLI.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would start with creating a web-enabled script which would be a Github commit hook. Probably in Node on a AWS instance which would then trigger the whole process of cleaning up (deleting) the old AWS instance and reinstalling a new AWS instance with the contents of your repository.

The exact method will be largely dependant on how your whole stack is setup.